# Windows Mobile Scrolling UI

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to develop a scrolling UI for Windows Mobile. Please suggest reference materials for me to get started.

Comment: A scrolling UI? What does that mean? Do you mean a touch-scroll list where you can use your finger to scroll fluently?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you narrow it down a bit:

1. Which programming language you use? C#, C++, Java
2. Can you choose the development environment?

Here's some pointers:

1. [Pocket PC developer network](http://pocketpcdn.com/)
2. [MSDN Windows Mobile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb847935.aspx)